# snake can't ride on edge of canvas in my JS game?

Tags: javascript

Hey guys I wrote a condition that would check the position of the snakes head to see if it hit the edge of the canvas. If this happens i wan't to stop the interval that the games running on. here's the code `//check if snake hit wall
    if(headX <= 0 || headY <= 0 || headX >= (cvsW-unit) || headY >= (cvsH-unit)) {
        alert(headX);
        clearInterval(runGame);
    }`
but sense the edge of the canvas has the x any y position of 0 this means if a food generates on the edge of the canvas the snake is unable to go there without the game stopping. And if you lower the values below 0 the snake head will now be able to go outside of the canvas. I don't know how to get around this plz help.

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector('#canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

//set canvas dimension equal to css dimension
canvas.width = 768;
canvas.height = 512;

//now put those dimensions into variables
const cvsW = canvas.width;
const cvsH = canvas.height;

//create snake unit
const unit = 16;

//create snake array
let snake = [{x: cvsW/2, y: cvsH/2}];

//delcare global variable to hold users direction
let direction;

//create food object
let food = {
 x : Math.floor(Math.random()*((cvsW/unit)-1)+1)*unit,
 y : Math.floor(Math.random()*((cvsH/unit)-1)+1)*unit
}

//read user's direction
document.addEventListener('keydown', changeDirection);

function changeDirection(e) {
 //set direction
 if (e.keyCode == 37 && direction != 'right') direction = 'left';
 else if (e.keyCode == 38 && direction != 'down') direction = 'up';
 else if (e.keyCode == 39 && direction != 'left') direction = 'right';
 else if (e.keyCode == 40 && direction != 'up') direction = 'down';
}

function draw() {
 //refresh canvas
 ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cvsW, cvsH);
 //draw snake
 for(let i = 0; i < snake.length; i++) {
  ctx.fillStyle = 'limegreen';
  ctx.fillRect(snake[i].x, snake[i].y, unit, unit);
 }

 //grab head position
 let headX = snake[0].x;
 let headY = snake[0].y;

 //check if snake hit wall
 if(headX <= 0 || headY <= 0 || headX >= (cvsW-unit) || headY >= (cvsH-unit)) {
  alert(headX);
  clearInterval(runGame);
 }

 //posistion food on board
 ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
 ctx.fillRect(food.x, food.y, unit, unit);

 //send the snake in chosen direction
 if(direction == 'left') headX -= unit;
 else if(direction == 'up') headY -= unit;
 else if(direction == 'right') headX += unit;
 else if(direction == 'down') headY += unit;

 //create new head
 let newHead = {x: headX, y: headY}

 if(headX == food.x && headY == food.y) {
  //create new food position
   food = {
   x : Math.floor(Math.random()*((cvsW/unit)-1)+1)*unit,
   y : Math.floor(Math.random()*((cvsH/unit)-1)+1)*unit
  }
  
  //add 3 units to the snake
  snake.unshift(newHead);
  snake.unshift(newHead);
  snake.unshift(newHead);
 }
 else {
  //remove tail
  snake.pop();
 }

 //add head to snake
 snake.unshift(newHead);
}

//run game engine
let runGame = setInterval(draw, 70);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Snake Game</title>
 <style>
  body {
   background-color: #333;
  }

  canvas {
   background-color: #4d4d4d;
   margin: auto;
   display: block;
   position: absolute;
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
   top: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   width: 750px;
   height: 500px;  
  }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
 <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
 <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, you have a 48x32 grid whose spaces are 16px squares. The algorithm you use to generate your food's position on the grid:

```
let food = {
     x : Math.floor(Math.random()*((cvsW/unit)-1)+1)*unit, // Chooses 1-47
     y : Math.floor(Math.random()*((cvsH/unit)-1)+1)*unit // Chooses 1-31
}
```

chooses a value between 1 and 47 for x, and 1 and 31 for y. Well, the problem with that is that position 47 for x and position 31 for y are both on the edge of the grid (this is because the first x/y position is 0, not 1). To eliminate those spaces as choices, the algorithm simply needs to subtract 2 instead of 1 from the number of spaces on the grid (which is cvsW or cvsH divided by unit):

```
let food = {
     x : Math.floor(Math.random()*((cvsW/unit)-2)+1)*unit, // Chooses 1-46
     y : Math.floor(Math.random()*((cvsH/unit)-2)+1)*unit // Chooses 1-30
}
```

Basically, subtracting 1 only eliminated the last column/row as a choice for the x/y position, and then adding 1 shifted everything over to the right. Like this (for x):

[image]

The new algorithm does this, initially eliminating the last two choices then shifting over 1:

[image]

Comment: thanks for your help, but this won't work because I want the food to to generate on the edge of the canvas and i also want the snake to be able to ride on the edge of the canvas

Comment: I think changing your wall-collision check code to exclude the edge values (i.e. x < 0 instead of x <=0) and moving that block of code so it performs the check before drawing the snake would work. Then the snake wouldn't be drawn out of bounds when it collides with the wall, and it can travel along the edge of the grid.